# Wrap Text In <span> beside a <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

In the above screen shot, the code looks like:

```
<label>Venue:<label>
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
<span id='msg'>Ang Mo Kio Int, Singapore <input type='button' class='smallbutton' value='Append This Address'></span>
```

I do not want the button to form a new line under the map, but new line under the text 'Ang Mo Kio Int, Singapore'. Any idea?

Update CSS:

```
label.form{
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
#map-canvas {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#msg{
    vertical-align:top;
}
input.smallbutton{
    background-color: #2d89ef !important;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 60px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Comment: can you post the CSS? it might be as simple as a "float: right", but I can't say for sure without the CSS of other elements.  "display: inline-block" is another possible solution.

Comment: @jqueryrocks thanks! I have updated my post with the css.

Comment: @CodeBender : add `span#msg{white-space:nowrap}`

Comment: hi @NoobEditor. Unfortunately, the entire string was below the map after adding "white-space:nowrap;". Wanted the string to be at the right side of the map. =D

Comment: @CodeBender : check `inline-block` as shown in below answe,if that doesn't work too, you'll have to provide a fiddle with map on it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be a problem with the google map Api that you are using. 
I don't know how the #msg content is loaded in the map. You should check on the google map api doc if it is possible to embed an input element on the map.

Comment: I think what you suggested was out of the box, but it helped to improve the website better. Thanks @Adrien.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JavaScript just grab the value of msg and set it `+= "<br>" + whatever`

Comment: hi roberto. I did a $('#msg').html(formatAddr+" <input type='button' class='smallbutton' value='Append This Address' onclick='appendAddress(\""+formatAddr+"\")'/>");

formatAddr is a value from reverse geocode event property.

Comment: sorry i dont know then :( im more of a java guy

Comment: the value is set dynamically. I don't think I want to manually chop the strings and place a <br> in between lines. If there any ways to do it dynamically? (like reading the width value?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css:

```
input.smallbutton {
  float: right;
}

span#msg {
...
float: right;
...
}
```

That should place it right next to the msg element.
To put it on a new line add a line break before the button in the HTML.

Comment: Hi. inline-block has already been set. Pardon that I left out input.smallbutton css earlier on. I have updated the css on my post. Thanks once again.

Comment: update post to reflect my other idea - float: right the two elements.  If that doesn't work then I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JS to find out location of span element with id msg and then dynamicaly set the location of button to below it.